# 9 Nested Fors without repeating the past number

Tags: java, optimization

I'm trying to get all the permutations for a 123456789. I'm using JTree. I can't get around this without burning my computer to the ground. Here's what I have:

```
 //create the root node
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
//create the child nodes
for (int x=1; x<10; x++){
    DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x);
    root.add(leaf);
    for (int x1=1; x1<9;x1++){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x1);          
        leaf.add(leaf1);
        for (int x2=1; x2<8;x2++){
            DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x2);
            leaf1.add(leaf2);
            for (int x3=1; x3<7;x3++){
                DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x3);
                leaf2.add(leaf3);
                for (int x4=1; x4<6;x4++){
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x4);
                    leaf3.add(leaf4);
                    for (int x5=1; x5<5;x5++){
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x5);
                        leaf4.add(leaf5);
                        for (int x6=1; x6<4;x6++){
                            DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x6);
                            leaf5.add(leaf6);
                            for (int x7=1; x7<3;x7++){
                                DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf7 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x7);
                                leaf6.add(leaf7);
                                for (int x8=1; x8<2;x8++){
                                    DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf8 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x8);
                                    leaf7.add(leaf8);
                                    for (int x9=1; x9<1;x9++){
                                        DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf9 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(x9);
                                        leaf8.add(leaf9);
                                    }
                                }
                            }   
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried if (x1 != x) but I would need to change the statement to x1<10 and so on. Is there any efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: There are probably prettier-looking approaches to it, but I doubt that you're going to get any better run-time efficiency than O(n!), since you're taking each possible permutation of that "string".

Comment: That prettier solution would be pre-compute all possible character permutations, then loop over all those by each character of a string to create your tree.

Comment: By "efficient" do you means "runs faster" (better Big-O or less wall-clock time?), or "uses less memory", or "fewer lines of code", or something else?

Comment: why no recursivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion. You will find the explanation of this algorithm [here](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/03/algorithm-to-find-permutations-of-string-using-recursion-in-java.html).

```
public class Permutations {
    private boolean[] used;
    private StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    private final String in;

    public Permutations(final String str) {
        in = str;
        used = new boolean[in.length()];
    }

    public void permute() {
        if (out.length() == in.length()) {
            System.out.println(out);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i) {
            if (used[i])
                continue;
            out.append(in.charAt(i));
            used[i] = true;
            permute();
            used[i] = false;
            out.setLength(out.length() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an use example of Permutations class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Permutations permutation = new Permutations("123");
        permutation.permute();
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```